# Running independent `nn.Module` instances in `nn.ModuleList` truly in parallel in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, parallel-processing

I have a PyTorch model that consists of multiple independent `FullyConnectedNetwork` instances stored inside an `nn.ModuleList`. Here's the code:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class FullyConnectedNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FullyConnectedNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

class ParallelFCN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(ParallelFCN, self).__init__()
        self.models = nn.ModuleList([FullyConnectedNetwork() for _ in range(n)])
    
    def forward(self, x):
        outputs = [model(x[:, i*20:(i+1)*20]) for i, model in enumerate(self.models)]
        return torch.cat(outputs, dim=1)

# Example usage:
n = 1000
model = ParallelFCN(n)
print(model)
```

Currently, I'm using a for-loop to pass data through each `FullyConnectedNetwork` instance. However, I realize that this approach is not truly parallel in a software sense.

Given that each `FullyConnectedNetwork` is independent of the others, is there a way to run them truly in parallel, perhaps using multi-threading, multi-processing, or any other method in PyTorch?

I need it because the number of my modules can get really big, as big as 400, and processing then using a for loop is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that it's somewhat handled by Cuda - it tries to execute kernels in async fashion within a stream, so kernel calls might overlap in time if it's possible. As far as I know, there is no explicit API in Pytorch to control it by yourself.

The most important part of Pytorch model's execution is that it's not really executed/interpreted as a python script - your model defines a computational graph that later would be **somehow** executed and managed by CUDA. It is especially true when it comes to real-world model deployment - ONNX, TensorRT and other have different execution strategies which are out of pytorch's control.

References:

- [Relevant discussion on Pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-l-run-two-blocks-in-parallel/61618#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20pipeline%20two,the%20first%20module%20have%20issued.&text=You%20could%20build%20large%20parallel%20branches%20by%20composing%20Parallel%20with%20Sequential%20.)
- **nn.Parallel** [feature request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36459)